# SQL join list of records from table as child list

Tags: sql, sql-server, netsuite

I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 co.company,
       cu.companyname,
       co.email,
       co.id,
       co.entitytitle,
FROM contact AS co
     LEFT JOIN customer as cu on cu.id = co.company
```

This gives me the following result:

```
[
    {
        "company": "78678678",
        "email": "ron@company.nl",
        "entitytitle": "Ron jans",
        "id": "745456"
    },
    {
        "company": "567477",
        "email": "bert.smit@company.nl",
        "entitytitle": "Bert smit",
        "id": "46547"
    }
]
```

I would like to join the tickets that are linked to the company in the same resultobject.
When I tried this query I get multiple results for the same contact for each ticket:

```
SELECT TOP 5 s.id as t,
       co.company,
       cu.companyname,
       co.email,
       co.id,
       co.entitytitle,
FROM contact AS co
     LEFT JOIN customer as cu on cu.id = co.company
     LEFT JOIN supportcase as s ON s.company = co.company
```

**CURRENT RESULT**

```
[
    {
        "t": "01"
        "company": "78678678",
        "email": "ron@company.nl",
        "entitytitle": "Ron jans",
        "id": "745456"
    },
    {
        "t": "02"
        "company": "78678678",
        "email": "ron@company.nl",
        "entitytitle": "Ron jans",
        "id": "745456"
    },
    {
        "t": "05"
        "company": "567477",
        "email": "bert.smit@company.nl",
        "entitytitle": "Bert smit",
        "id": "46547"
    }
]
```

**WANTED RESULT**

```
[
    {
        "company": "78678678",
        "email": "ron@company.nl",
        "entitytitle": "Ron jans",
        "id": "745456",
        "tickets": [{"t": "01"}, {"t": "02"}]
    },
    {
        "company": "567477",
        "email": "bert.smit@company.nl",
        "entitytitle": "Bert smit",
        "id": "46547"
        "tickets": [{"t": "05"}]
    }
]
```

How can I achieve this?
Im using this netsuite endpoint:

```
https://<accountnumber>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql
```

Comment: While SQL Server does have the ability to produce JSON output the T-SQL queries you've shown in the question don't produce such JSON results. How are you doing that currently?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning this is the output that the Netsuite suiteQL API produces. Netsuite makes use of mssql. Im using `https://<accountnumber>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql`

Comment: "SuiteQL" is one of many dialects of SQL that APIs offer to do SQL-like querying. It is not T-SQL (the dialect of SQL Server), whether or not they "make use" of SQL Server under the covers (which seems unlikely, given that it's an Oracle product, but what do I know). A quick perusal of the syntax does not suggest they support either explicit JSON markup or nested tables, so it's unlikely you can get exactly that output with only a SQL query, you'd have to do some post-processing yourself.